# Cant edit DT tag with CSS3

Tags: html, css

Perhaps someone can help me a bit with this, i'm having a really big headache with this. I've got an assignment due that requires us to edit the DT tags to be a dark blue, specifically #000033 in color. I have this as my CSS code right now

```
dt {
   color: #000033;
}
```

and while it doesn't change the DT tags, it does change the DD tags into a mild greyish color... Which completely confuses me, because I'm not even touching the DD tags in my CSS and have absolutely no embedded style inside of the DD tags either.

Anyone that's able to help, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: assign id or class to your dt tag using id or class use styling at dt tag.

Comment: Works for me, is that all CSS you have or you have something else too? http://jsfiddle.net/FJc9B/

Comment: I have a few more calls, but nothing that should conflict with the DT tags that I know of. They should be working fine as far as my understanding goes, if you'd like to take a look at the actual page, it's www.smithwebdesigns.com/a4/yurts.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule is saying `.dt { }`, not `dt { }`.

This is telling it to find any element with the class name "dt", rather than all elements of type `dt`.

Once you fix that, it will work :)

Comment: Ya, I had it the other way before as well, it wasn't working either, i'll update it now to what it was originally, not being a class, just re-assigning the DT Tags properties.

Comment: Ah, hell, look at that, now it's working lol, it was straight Black before, now it's the dark blue it should be. No clue what happened to fix it lol, gotta love CSS. Thanks for your help! As well as everyone else!

Comment: How did you even got that he was using `.`

Comment: He checked my CSS, I would imagine.

Comment: @Mr.Alien One of Enigma's earlier comments had the website URI, so I just checked it and checked the CSS. Then I changed it to `dt { color: #f00; }` to confirm it worked :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien Uhh I actually meant to say, "magic" *shimmies hands*